# Can I create a tag for Perl6 module installer panda?

Tags: discussion, tags

I just posted [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41416011/100754) about Perl 6's module installer [panda](https://github.com/tadzik/panda), but when I tried to tag the question with `panda`, I was told the tag `pandas` already exists and therefore I should raise this on meta.

How should this be handled?

Comment: Will you answer the questions with that tag?

Comment: @Braiam What does that even mean? I am using `panda` to install Perl6 modules. I don't know much about it (hence the question). That does not preclude the possibility that I might answer questions in that tag in the future when I know, but I do not understand how my commitment to answering questions can be a part of the decision to tag a separate area of questions.

Comment: Since ["\[t\]ags are a means of connecting experts with questions they will be able to answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging), if there's nobody committed to answer the questions with that tag, what will happen when someone ask a question with just that tag? There will be no way the question would be answered, right?

Comment: I am assuming there are other people who use Perl6 who will be using `panda`. At least some among us will likely be able to answer questions.

Comment: Well, let them to add the tag when they feel the need for it. Right now, creating a new tag which we don't know if someone will follow is a very real possibility and, as you noted, there's a general tag that fits and we can have some reassurance that those questions would be answered.

Comment: I feel like I am living in Kafka's "Trial" here. I am ***asking*** a question related to Perl 6's `panda` module installer. I want to label my question with the appropriate classification. I do not understand how classifying something can be prevented by the requirement that I first find people to underwrite a question-answering policy. By labeling my question with the specific category, I would be making it discoverable by people who want to answer questions in that category -- if I were allowed.

Answer (score -3):

This question is rather old now. If I had answered it then, my opinion would have been to use a more generic `package-management` tag instead of the specific one. My opinion *now* is that, well, panda is no longer used or maintained, and I don't think `zef` is popular enough for a tag, so still no.

Comment: At the time, I thought after almost two decades in development, Perl 6 had a default package manager, and `panda` was it ... kind of like [cpan](https://metacpan.org/pod/cpan). I did not think it was going to be dumped unceremoniously. ... The question is kind of pointless now as I am no longer interested in *asking* questions about any aspect of Perl 6 let alone about a [package manager that makes me work so hard to bend to its will](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41416011/100754).